# Why isn't bitbucket prompting me for an app password?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I tried this:

```
git clone https://me@bitbucket.org/sdfsdfsdf/csdfsdfs.git
```

Get an error saying SSO is enabled and I need to login with an app password- but I created an app password so why isn't it prompting me for one?

Then I did this:

```
git clone https://me:mypasswordwtf@bitbucket.org/sdfsdfsdf/csdfsdfs.git
```

That works but now that password is hard-coded into git metadata. if I do `git remote -v` I can see it in the remote URL which is bad for obvious reasons

In cases where I can't use ssh, is there any safe way to use app passwords? otherwise I'll have to disable SSO to prevent everyone from adding secrets in their command history and local git configs.

Answer (score 0):

> but I created an app password so why isnt it prompting me for one?

Check if you have set a credential helper:

```
git config credential.helper
```

If not, make sure to use `[manager-cor][1]e` (with the latest Git 2.28), which should give you the opportunity to cache your password.

Answer (score 0):

Your credential helper has saved the old credentials you were using for this account.  As the [Git FAQ entry for this issue states](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIchangethepasswordortokenI8217vesavedinmycredentialmanager), you can run a command like this to remove the existing credentials:

```
$ echo url=https://author@git.example.org | git credential reject
```

Note that if you're using Git Credential Manager for Windows (that is, `git config -l | grep credential.helper` shows `manager`), then this doesn't work because of [this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/703) and you should follow the steps outlined [in this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/871#issuecomment-622827349) as a workaround.  You may wish to use a different credential helper in the meantime.